# depmixS4 Hiden Markov Model HMM data formula

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models

I am attempting to use the `depmixS4` package in R for an HMM analysis, but am struggling with how to properly format my data for use in the `depmix()` function. My goal is to identify two states within the provided `train` data.

Here is the code I am using to generate the `train` data:

```r
state1 <- rnorm(500, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5)
state2 <- rnorm(500, mean = -1, sd = 1.5)

train <- c(state1[1:100], state2[1:100], state1[101:200], state2[101:200])

X.tr <- embed(train, dimension = 5)[,5:1] |> as.data.frame()
plot(X.tr$V5, t = "l", main = "state1 and state2")
```

The resulting plot is as follows:

[image]

I am unsure how to format my response in the `depmix()` function for multi-dimensional `X.tr` data. Here is the code I currently have:

```r
library(depmixS4)

# Set up the model
mod <- depmix( ___??___ , data = X.tr, nstates = 2)

# Fit the model
hmm <- fit(mod)
```

What should I use for `___??___` to properly format the response variable for the `depmix()` function?

Comment: Which columns of `X.tr` are considered as response variable?

Comment: This is just a data.frame, where each row is one observation, if I understand correctly, it means that all columns are a response

Comment: By providing the formula `V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + V5 ~ 1` as the response variable in depmix(), you can treat each column (V1 to V5) as a separate response variable.

Comment: You're welcome. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254105/discussion-between-hossein-taghizad-and-mr-t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + V5 ~ 1` as the formula to the response. It specifies that all columns (V1 to V5) in `X.tr` are considered as response variables, and the `~ 1` indicates that there are no covariates.